# adding pay by credit card to my android app

Tags: android

So there is website for company and they are selling products on the website. they decided to do mobile app for this website.

**The Quesiton is**: so how is it possible to add the paying by credit card functionality to my app ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Stripe? it is great! It has a great API and good integration with the mobile app

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android